# The simplest way to write files locally on Windows by client JS

Tags: javascript, java

I know that client JavaScript in browser normally can't write files locally on Windows disk because of security reasons.

At the same time I heard that it's possible with some additional tool(s) or workaround(s) and I'm looking for the simplest one with minimum lines of code or/and with minimum size.

The ways and workarounds I heard or read about but some of them are not reliable and other ones are just not suitable for me:

[*won't explain why]

- a local LAMP-server like WAMP, XAMP etc.
- local version of NodeJS
- HTA file with JS + Windows ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')
- Chrome's HTML5 File API and Filesystem API
- creating and downloading a Blob file

I read that JavaScript can load Java applet and the applet can get access to file system, but I don't know Java at all and don't know what to get started with. And I heard about Silverlight but I also don't know it.

Or maybe there is even more simple way

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood things. Locally run JS in Node.js can write to the filesystem yes. So can server-side languages. You can't use JS as a client-side scripting language to write to a file within the browser scope (think about it, where would the file go?). You should state *why* you feel the need to do this, and people can tell you why you shouldn't, and how you can otherwise accomplish your task.

Answer (score 0):

An easy implementation is to use an anchor tag with embedded data:

```html
<a href="data:text,this is the content of the text file" download="filename.txt">Download File</a>
```

as for embedding different kinds of data into your href tag, look into "data uri scheme". 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

I have used this type of embedding for excel files, pdfs, images, you name it.

There is also a programmatic approach in pure javascript, which relies on the same trick of creating an anchor tag in javascript and running the click function on it:

```
var a = document.createElement('a')
a.download = "filename.txt"
a.href = 'data:text,this is the content of the text file'
a.click()
```